# Is there a way to protect a smart pointer from being deallocated on one thread, when work is being done on another thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, c++17

In our program, we have a class `FooLogger` which logs specific events (strings). We use the `FooLogger` as a `unique_ptr`.

We have two threads which use this `unique_ptr` instance:

1. Thread 1 logs the latest event to file in a while loop, first checking if the instance is not `nullptr`
2. Thread 2 deallocates the `FooLogger` `unique_ptr` instance when the program has reached a certain point (set to `nullptr`)

However, due to bad interleaving, it is possible that, while logging, the member variables of `FooLogger` are deallocated, resulting in an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

```
class FooLogger {
  public:
    FooLogger() {};

    void Log(const std::string& event="") {
      const float32_t time_step_s = timer_.Elapsed() - runtime_s_; // Can get EXC_BAD_ACCESS on timer_
      runtime_s_ += time_step_s;

      std::cout << time_step_s << runtime_s_ << event << std::endl;
    }

  private:      
    Timer timer_; // Timer is a custom class
    float32_t runtime_s_ = 0.0;
};


int main() {
  auto foo_logger = std::make_unique<FooLogger>();

  std::thread foo_logger_thread([&] {
    while(true) {
      if (foo_logger)
        foo_logger->Log("some event");
      else
        break;
    }
  });

  SleepMs(50); // pseudo code
  foo_logger = nullptr;

  foo_logger_thread.join();
}
```

Is it possible, using some sort of thread synchronisation/locks etc. to ensure that the `foo_logger` instance is not deallocated while logging? If not, are there any good ways of handling this case?

Comment: If you create a copy of a shared pointer, it will automatically do this. That's what a shared pointer is for.

Comment: Your talking about `std::shared_ptr` in your code, but your example shows an `std::unique_ptr`. It seems to me you need a `shared_ptr` in the "owning" thread, and a `weak_ptr` in the logging thread. If you clear the `shared_ptr` in the "owning" thread, the logging thread will notice it can't create a `shared_ptr` from its `weak_ptr`.

Comment: @AVH I've corrected to be `unique_ptr` in the description above. Interesting point about `weak_ptr` -  I haven't had any experience using `weak_ptr` so let me investigate that a bit more on my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of `std::unique_ptr` is to deallocate the instance once `std::unique_ptr` is out of scope. In your case, you have multiple threads each having access to the element and the owning thread might get eliminated prior to other users.

You either need to ensure that owner thread never gets deleted prior to the user threads or change ownership model from `std::unique_ptr` to `std::shared_ptr`. It is the whole purpose of `std::shared_ptr` to ensure that the object is alive as long as you use it.

You just need to figure out what's required for program and use the right tools to achieve it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a different mechanism than the disappearance of an object for determining when to stop.
(When you use a single thing for two separate purposes, you often get into trouble.)

For instance, an atomic `bool`:

```
int main() {
  FooLogger foo_logger;
  std::atomic<bool> keep_going = true;  
  std::thread foo_logger_thread([&] {
    while(keep_going) {
        foo_logger.Log("some event");
    }
  });

  SleepMs(50);
  keep_going = false;
  foo_logger_thread.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like [`std::weak_ptr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr) can help in this case.

You can make one from a `std::shared_ptr` and pass it to the logger thread.

For example:

```
class FooLogger {
public:
    void Log(std::string const& event) {
        // log the event ...
    }
};

int main() {
    auto shared_logger = std::make_shared<FooLogger>();

    std::thread foo_logger_thread([w_logger = std::weak_ptr(shared_logger)]{
        while (true) {
            auto logger = w_logger.lock();
            if (logger)
                logger->Log("some event");
            else
                break;
        }
    });

    // some work ...

    shared_logger.reset();

    foo_logger_thread.join();
}
```

Comment: `while (auto logger = w_logger.lock()) { logger->Log("some event"); }` is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Use should use make_shared instead of make_unique. And change:

```
  std::thread foo_logger_thread([&] {
```

to

```
  std::thread foo_logger_thread([foo_logger] {
```

It will create new instance of shared_ptr.

Comment: This will keep the logger alive forever.

Comment: This solution is *generally* what you want with shared pointers, but not in OP’s specific case, which instead requires an observer (e.g. via a weak pointer), or some other cross-thread communication.